# C# equivalent to trace() from Actionscript-3?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, debugging, trace

I'm sorry if the question is stupid but I'm still curious.

Is there anything as short as `trace(...)` in C# ?

The best I can get in C# is `MyClass.MyMethod(...);`

Or can I redirect <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in VS2010 to a code snippet other than `Console.WriteLine();`?

Comment: no C# doesn't have methods "floating in the air" which don't belong to a class. That makes no sense in OOP. C# is a real, serious programming language, not some random flash thing used to show pictures of dancing monkeys in commercial ads in web pages. And yes, you can add as many snippets as you want in Visual Studio.

Comment: What's wrong with `Console.WriteLine`? You could also use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write()` method I guess but that's even longer to type. It outputs to the Output window.

Comment: @DaveZych I can't use `Console.WriteLine` because I need my output to go through **my** class that writes them to both log files and console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new snippets yourself..

Look in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\` or where you installation is done. And create a new snippet.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>trace</Title>
            <Shortcut>trace</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine</Description>
            <Author>You</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($end$);]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And name it: `trace.snippet`

Maybee you need to restart visual studio, but now you can use:

`trace` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Now I learned that there is more than `cw` in VS2010 and also how to use `for`, `try` ... code snippets. It was a good day. Thanks!